# How to correct display the color in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

In XAML i write color is #252834, and on app a get #272735.
In XAML i write color is #AC8FFF, and on app a get #AC8FFF.The light shades are displayed as it should be
What could be the problem?
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9srj.png)

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="#252834"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you show your code.

Comment: Please add the code to your question and no image of the code please.

Comment: I tryed your code in Visual Studio 2019 and the latest Maui pre version but the result is the same. #242832 and not #252834 like in Setter, i used PowerToys Picker . So different results and also not what you found . Maybe a resulotion or other ColorPicker problem ? Used Free version of Vysor installed on Windows pc